# Show that $Q$ admits a unique root in an epsilon ball about a simple root

Tags: real-analysis

Let $P(x) = p_0 x^m + p_1 x^{m-1}+\cdots+p_m$ where the coefficients in $P$ are real numbers and $p_0  \neq 0.$ Furthermore suppose that $x_0$ is a simple root of $P$, or $P(x_0) = 0$ and $P'(x_0)\neq 0$.

I want to show that there exists a $\delta,\epsilon>0$ such that for every $|q_0-p_0|<\delta$, $|q_1-p_1|<\delta$, $\dots$, $|q_m-p_m|<\delta$, the polynomial $Q(x) = q_0x^m+q_1x^{m-1}+\cdots+q_m$ admits a unique root in an epsilon ball of $x_0$,  $B_\epsilon(x_0)$.

In order to prove this I should use something from the inverse and/or implicit function theorems but am stuck on how to start and continue through the problem. Could I have any help ? Thanks.

Comment: I edited your title, replacing $Q$ by $P$, since $Q$ does not appear in the body of your post, whilst $P$ does.

Comment: I put the $Q$ back; sorry.